# PDO fetchObject doesn't work with some private fields

Tags: php, pdo

I am struggling with PDO fetchObject.

I have a Supplier class:

```
class Supplier {

private $id;
private $companyName;
private $vatNumber;
private $address;
private $phoneNumber;
private $email;
private $responsible;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAddress()
{
    return $this->address;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $address
 */
public function setAddress($address)
{
    $this->address = $address;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCompanyName()
{
    return $this->companyName;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $companyName
 */
public function setCompanyName($companyName)
{
    $this->companyName = $companyName;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getResponsible()
{
    return $this->responsible;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $responsible
 */
public function setResponsible($responsible)
{
    $this->responsible = $responsible;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getVatNumber()
{
    return $this->vatNumber;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $vatNumber
 */
public function setVatNumber($vatNumber)
{
    $this->vatNumber = $vatNumber;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPhoneNumber()
{
    return $this->phoneNumber;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $phoneNumber
 */
public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)
{
    $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
}
}
```

Then I call getById in SupplierDAO:

```
public function getById($id) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM supplier where id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt->execute(array($id))) {
        $supplier = $stmt->fetchObject('Supplier');
    }

    $stmt = null;
    $dbh = null;

    return $supplier;

}
```

When I manage the returned value from getById (in a json), I see:

```
{"error":"",
"status":"",
"supplier":{
    "company_name":"XXXX",
    "vat_number":"111111",
    "phone_number":"069341527",
    "created":"2018-02-23 14:33:09",
    "updated":"2018-02-23 14:33:09"
 }
}
```

Why I don't see address field, email field and responsible field?

I saw, in some post, that the solution is to change the visibility of the fields, from private to public (and indeed it works), but I don't like it.

Have you some tips to give me, or maybe I wrong something?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Would help to see the schema of that table. Also, why no constructor? If you want direct (external access) to those values, then yes, you need to make them public, not private.

Comment: A tip that might be relevant, in particular if this is for a JSON response, is to have a implement [jsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) in your entity class, which will let you determine what field you want output, and since it's in the class, it has access to private properties.

Comment: Well, the issue is that the pdo stmt object cannot assign the private variables (because they are private). So they end up empty no matter how you post-access those variables. The `getById($id)` function should be inside the Supplier class so it has access to the private variables. Or part of a parent and use protected variables. Either way, if you don't want public variables, there is some restructuring involved :(

Comment: for other class, where I had add some extra fields, not belonging directly to the entity, I implemented jsonSerializable. But in this case, I dont' need extra field, but only all fields of the entity Supplier. And also, I don't understand why created and updated, which are only field on databse, are shown in my json

Comment: @Gjord83 I don't know where created and updated come from either, since theres no code showing where those even began or came from ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat help me to understand. I understand what you said, but I don't understand why companyName, which is private field, is shown...

Comment: It is? I'm sorry, but without the table schema, I have no idea what variables should be named, or what would cross over. The general sense of fetchObject is, fields of `such_n_such` name map directly to `public` variables of that object. So the object variables must be exactly named the same. But I cannot tell, you have a `*` for your `SELECT`.

Comment: Ah, it's because you have no normalisation. The working properties work because the column names don't match the private properties, so fetchObject is actually doing e.g. `$entity->company_name = value` (which when not defined, is public), not `$entity->companyName`. Address and e-mail don't work because they do match the names of your private properties and you can't set private properties directly from the outside.

Comment: GREAT!!! Now I finally understand. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: But... If I have the name of the private field equals to the name of the table field, what is the best solution? To implement JsonSerializable, or to have public field in the entity?

Comment: JsonSerializable isn't going to help you set private variables. Your best bet might be to have a magic `__set` method that corrects the variable name from column -> property name, then calls the relevant set method, or sets the property. Another option is to use an already existing library to deal with this stuff :P

Comment: may you give me an example?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Just do some searching around __set and converting underscore delimited strings to camel case.

Comment: but I have to use the magic method for field which have the same name on the database?

Comment: @JonStirling but I want to set address variable for example, no companyName

Comment: @Gjord83 Sorry, I can't work out what you're asking.

Comment: You suggested me to use __set magic method, I never used it. I had a look on google, but it seems to be for the fields which are equals to the fields of the table. In my case, if I implement __get or __set I cannot see, anyway, address, responsible ad email field...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify which fields to include in json_encode you can try [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php).